# Angular call login microsoft api

Tags: .net, angular, microsoft-graph-api

I have an angular application that requires calling the microsoft oatuh2/token API to retrieve a token to call a specific API. I make a direct http client call because I don’t want the Microsft login page:

```
const urlToken = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANTID}/oauth2/v2.0/token';

const bodyToken = new HttpParams()
.set('client_id', '{client_id}')
.set('scope', 'https://search.azure.com/.default')
.set('client_secret', '{client_secret}')
.set('grant_type', 'client_credentials'); 

this.httpClient.post(urlToken, bodyToken.toString(),
{
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

}).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

But this call is returning a CORS error.
How to call this endpoint via my Angular front or via a Dotnet API located in a private area

Comment: using `/.default` means you are using client credential flow. and if you want to use this flow to call microsoft graph api, the scope should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. Since what you used in your code snippet is not, I'm afraid you already exposed API and created role for this app, pls don't forget to add api permission.

Answer (score 0):

`you don’t want the Microsft login page`  --> using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to authorize your request to call graph api --> you must use a `daemon app` to call this endpoint  --> [client credential sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#service--daemon) here.

Or referring to asp.net core code like below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var res = await graphClient.Users["example@example.com"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Cors issue is because you have to use MSAL(microsoft authentication library) to do the authentication and authorization. And this is why Angular app is not able to authenticate without a sign in page. You have to do it in `daemon` app so that it can authenticate on behalf an application instead of a user.